# Override @ManyToOne targetEntity for @Embedded with interfaces

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using hibernate and annotations for ORM.
I have interfaces for all beans and I am using targetEntity for relationships:
hibernate cannot derive the type because the getter returns an interface rather than a bean.

I get a MappingException (could not determine type) for embedded beans.

```
@Entity(name="FieldBean")
public class FieldBean implements Field {
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class FacetBean implements Facet {
    ...    

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = FieldBean.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "field_id")
    public Field getField() {
        return field;
    }

}

@Entity(name = "Chart")
public class ChartBean implements Chart {

    @Embedded
    @AssociationOverride(
        name = "field",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "category_facet_field_id")
    )
    public Facet getCategoryFacet() {
        return categoryFacet;
    }

}
```

I get the MappingException: Could not determine type for: Field, at table: chart, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(field)]

Using beans instead of interfaces for property and getter/setter declarations solves the problem, but I would like to stick to using interfaces. Using beans for property declarations alone does not solve the problem.

Could anyone point me in the right direction ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used a workable solution to this for a while now, but it includes a minor case of vendor lock-in. I have found no way of doing this with JPA annotations only, but there is a Hibernate-specific annotation `@Target` that does the trick. I have done something like you have, with the expected results. However, I didn't use your other annotations so I can't guarantee it will turn out to work as you expect.

Nothing strange going on in the Embeddable classes:

```
public interface PointsInt extends Serializable {
    int offensivePoints();

    int defensivePoints();

}

@Embeddable
public class Points implements PointsInt {
    private int def;
    private int off;
    public int offensivePoints() { return off; }

    public int defensivePoints() { return def; }

}
```

But in the consuming class, we use Hibernate's `@Target`:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Target;

@Entity
public class Series extends LongIdEntity implements Serializable {

    @Embedded
    @Target(Points.class)
    private PointsInt points;
    // I prefer to declare my annotations on fields rather than methods
}
```

Result:

```
mysql> describe series;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | bigint(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| def             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| off             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

My past using jpa told me not to use inheritance. No mapped superclasses, no interfaces, etc ... simply entities with members. i worked with hibernate as well as eclipselink and both have really, really problems with inheritance. It is relly difficulty to write a persistence layer with jpa that supports more than one provider, as there are so many bugs all these providers. keep it as simple as possible. don't use any "special" features. i assure you, when trying to change the provider or simply running a software on different applications servers like jboss (hibernate) or glassfish/weblogic (eclipse/top link), you can be glad when having a most simply persistence layer that uses as little features as possible. i don't know if this is a bug, but i'd assume it is.

Comment: I am using interfaces and inheritance. Admitted that this introduced some complexity at the level of the ORM. On the other hand, it does provide me with the level of abstraction I am looking for.

Comment: **Interfaces** are used to provide abstraction of the ORM technology. Using an MDA approach, I generate the persistence layer code out of an object model, including interfaces, beans and service classes. An alternative ORM technology could be used transparently by keeping the interfaces stable but generating alternative beans and service classes.

Comment: **Inheritance** is needed from a data modeling perspective to support both the general and specific views on the data, in particular but not exclusively at the relational database level. Despite some of the disadvantages, the feature remains useful and simplifies code at higher levels in the application stack.

Comment: **Embedding** is less critical, as it concerns only the table structure and it does not impact the interface layer. It is only for embedding that I am missing the required annotations to override the association parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the discussion of whether interfaces are over-used, the root of your issue is that you're using interfaces, where classes are expected. Specifically, you're putting a JPA annotation on a method that returns a non-JPA object.

The solution is very simply: put the annotations on the fields, instead of the methods.

```
@Embeddable
public class FacetBean implements Facet {

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = FieldBean.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "field_id")
    private FieldBean field;

    public Field getField() {
        return field;
    }
}
```

The only drawback that this has is that you're going to have issues with any setter methods, if you insist of having one with a `Field` parameter. But you're going to have such problems anyway, if you want to be able to assign any `Field` instance, even if it isn't a JPA-managed bean.